# Does the grand sum of the inverse of a matrix decrease if we increase one element?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Let $\bf A$ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix. Assume that we modify $\bf A$ so that some element $a_{ij}$ with $i \neq j$ becomes $a_{ij} + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ (note that $a_{ji}$ also becomes $a_{ji} + \varepsilon$ so that the new matrix ${\bf \tilde{A}}$ is also symmetric). It is clear that the grand sum of ${\bf \tilde{A}}$ is greater than the grand sum of $\bf A$, i.e.,

$${\bf 1}^\top {\bf \tilde{A}} {\bf 1} > {\bf 1}^\top {\bf A} {\bf 1}.$$

Is it also true that the following inequality holds?

$${\bf 1}^\top \left({\bf \tilde{A}}\right)^{-1} {\bf 1} < {\bf 1}^\top {\bf A}^{-1} {\bf 1}.$$

---

**Motivation**

This question matters to me for showing that if there are signals $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$ following a joint normal distribution with mean $(\theta,\dots,\theta)$ and variance $A$, and $\theta$ follows an improper diffuse distribution, the posterior variance of $\theta$ conditional on $k<n$ signals for agent $i$ would increase if we take out one of the signals and introduce another one more correlated to hers.

Comment: Interesting question. I think the way to approach it is to view the change as a low rank update, and use the woodbury formula

Comment: You have a rank-2 update of $A$. Like Nick wrote, use [Woodbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: Thank you, but after using Woodbury, I need to prove
$$(C^{-1}+V\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}U)^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}UV\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}>0$$
which so far I was completely unable to show...
$U=(1 0 ... 0)$, $V=(0 1 0 ... 0)^t$ and $C$ is a real number

Comment: @RiskyMike You will have an easier problem, since the tricky matrix inverse will be $2 \times 2$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what do you mean by "the tricky matrix inverse will be 2x2"...

Comment: @RiskyMike Take a look at the Wikipedia page. I mean the inverse of the sum of matrices

Comment: I think the inverse of the sum of matrices on the left is just a real number, but still I have no clue whether it is positive or not...

Comment: @RiskyMike It should be a 2x2 matrix since you have a rank-2 update